# What does the '?' symbol mean in a .htaccess rewrite condition?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, symbols

I have been reading the Rewrite condition info in the Apache documentation but have got nowhere, so I hope you can help. In my .htaccess file I had some lines that ran thus:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

I have since noticed that a dollar sign was missing from line 3, so it should have run thus:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com$ [nc]
```

So my question has two parts, was it working (doing anything) originally (and what??)? And if not, how was it interpreted with the missing '$'. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says `?` but probably mean missing anchor `$` from your regex.

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com$ [nc]
```

Even more correct would be:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain\.com$ [nc]
```

Since dot can mean anything in regex and literal dot needs to be escaped.

Without `$` also it might work but in theory it can match `mydomain.comp` also. With `$` in place it can only match `mydomain.com`

Comment: Yes! I confused myself (but not you!) by mixing up the ? and the $, but I re-edited it and it reads as it should now. Thanks.

Comment: OK did you check my answer? Do you need more clarification on this?